# ASP.NET HTTP Authorization Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I would like to know why my asp.net application will not add the header to my post when it is named 'Authorization' but will work fine when I change one character, say "Authorizations". In documentation for other sites they always use the name "Authorization" so I would like to as well and at this point I just want to under stand why.

I have read a few topics about this but have not found any logical reason why.

Here is my code below:

```
string fileName = "c:\\xyz.xml";
string uri = "http://myserver/Default.aspx";
req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("DDSServices:jCole2011".ToCharArray());
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BASIC " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes) );
req.Headers.Add("test", "test");
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
reqStream.Close();
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BASIC" + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes));
System.Net.WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The other annoying this is when i add the watched variable through fiddler it works fine.

Answer (score 43):

I was ran into a question how to add Authentication/Credentials to the headers. I found the solution in the following way.

```
string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "myUser","myPwd");
string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = _cred;
```

Which gave me those headers I want (pasted Wireshark descriptions),

> Authorization: Basic bXlVc2VyOm15UHdk\r\n 
>   Credentials: myUser:myPwd

Comment: So how do you know for sure the encoding to use is ASCII?

Comment: Nice point. The choosen encoding looks like a possible "hard to find"-source for bugs. I add the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication for readers to find more information of how to decide.

Answer (score 11):

For HTTP Basic Authorization, you should be using the Credentials property.

`req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("DDSServices", "jCole2011");`

This should do what you want. Rather than setting the Authorization header.

Comment: or is there a logical reason? A very large third party company that we work with has documentation with their authorization in the same manner, so I would like to know the reason.

Comment: It is much better to use the NetworkCredential approach as Will suggests. However, your approach should also work fine, although I dont understand why you are doing it twice (one before call to GetRquestStream, and once after. You should do it jsut once before y ou call GetRequestStream. If it still doesnt work, get a trace log. Instructions at http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html

Comment: Can you tell me why it is better? Or where i can read about why it is better? To me it seems NetworkCredentials would be tied in with ad or forms authentication, I would rather the connection be through anonymous, then just verify. Either way though can someone just tell me why? I almost don't care about what at this point.

Comment: Well A) Because it works, and B) Because .NET will do the authentication negotiation for you automatically. Is the third party also using .NET?

Comment: More information on using NetworkCredential is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx - it can be used for any of the authentication schemes supported, and only uses the credentials you pass in.

Comment: NetworkCredential only sends the Authentication header after a 401 is received. This is probably not what you want...

Use the old fashion way:
`var credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(aUserName + ":" + aPassword);
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);`

Comment: @Hupperware Unless you set PreAuthenticate=true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate.aspx

Comment: @WillHughes That's not true. I tried to use the PreAuthenticate=true but it was not working. The link you posted verifies that you need to catch the 401 the first time.  "Property Value
Type: System.Boolean
true to send an HTTP Authorization header with requests after authentication has taken place; otherwise, false. The default is false."

Answer (score 3):

NetworkCredential is a good solution but the site you are calling has to handle an unauthorized with a 401 AND a WWW-Authenticate header in the response.

Client:

```
request.Credentials = new CredentialCache {{aUri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(aUserName, aPassword)}};
```

Server:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
Response.End();
```

This will result in 2 hits to the server. The initial call will go to the server without credentials. When the server responds with a 401 AND the WWW-Authenticate header (with the type of authentication required), the request will be resent with the credentials in the request.

Comment: This is true, but sending back 401 Unauthorized, and the WWW-Authenticate header is part of the HTTP Spec. If you want to force sending the header on the first request, you can do so through the PreAuthenticate method.  In Addition - IIS automatically handles sending back this response, as do other well-written HTTP servers such as Apache. It's how browsers know to display the password prompt dialog.